# Error when log in my partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, bootloader

**

- I want to install Ubuntu beside my windows 8 but I made a mistake
  that i installed only Ubuntu ,but when I logged in Ubuntu and went to
  open my partitions , an error appeared said that "This partition is
  in unsafe state and I cannot open it".

**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Windows 8 enabled UEFI's secure boot mode,  this tries to prevent root kits.

Go into UEFI(Normally F2),  look around till you see "Secure Boot" and hit disable.

Comment: I found that I work on BIOS not UEFI through this http://kb.parallels.com/en/115815 
but i go to boot menu and did not find any thing about secure boot

Comment: I want to know what I should do ?!!

Comment: this is the error which was I talking about "Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/abdo/mohamed: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/abdo/mohamed"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option".